# Explode jQuery Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, database, explode

I have a problem to explode an array in jQuery.

[image]

I wanna explode array and insert them to database with parent section

Thanks for ur help

Comment: What problem are you facing? Can you post your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why you need to explode? Here is an short example how to have access to the array with objects.

```js
 var input = [{"id" : 1, "parent" : 0}, {"id" : 2, "parent": 0, "children": [{"id": 3, "parent": 2}]}];
 
 input.forEach(function(object, index) {
  console.log("Id: " + object.id);
        window.document.write("<br>Id: " + object.id + "<br>");
  console.log("Parent: " + object.parent);
        window.document.write("Parent: " + object.parent + "<br>");
  
  if(typeof object.children !== 'undefined') {
   console.log("Has Children: true");
            window.document.write("Has Children: true" + "<br>");
   object.children.forEach(function(childObject, childIndex) {
    console.log("Child-Id: " + childObject.id);
    console.log("Child-Parent: " + childObject.parent);
                window.document.write("Child-Id: " + childObject.id + "<br>");
                window.document.write("Child-Parent: " + childObject.parent + "<br>");
   });
  }
      else {
        console.log("Has Children: false");
        window.document.write("Has Children: false" + "<br>");
      }
  
  console.log("----------------");
        window.document.write("----------------");
 });
```

If you want each part of section:

```
input.splice(',')
Outputs: {"id" : 1, "parent" : 0}
         {"id" : 2, "parent": 0, "children": [{"id": 3, "parent": 2}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php explode equivalent function in js which is

```
var str = "string to be exploded and seperated each item by space";
var res = str.split(" ");
```